# how to restive/get all service instances value in Tibco Administrator?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-topic

In Tibco Administrator I've more then 30 application. i want to get all details of each application inside configuration and service instances is there anyway to export all data?

Comment: What is Tibco version? In Tibco BW5 all the deployed packages settings are in text files in folder \tra\domain\tibco_dev514\application\  or \tra\domain\tibco_dev514\datafiles\ you can write powershell script for parsing the files

Comment: David i'm using BW5.10 but my all application are running on web sever. a& i don't have much knowledge on power shell script...

Comment: It's not clear what is "all details of each application inside configuration and service instances" . In tibcoBW context the application is .ear package deployed to TibcoBW. Could you please specify what details about the application do you need?

Comment: for the ex: in the application service Instance we have state from there we can check the application is running or not.. 
we have lot of other details like tracing logs, Statistics processes, alerts ext.